# Java cannot find a class in a .jar file in Linux

Tags: java, linux, class, exception, jar

I built a java program in Eclipse in Windows and it worked well. The program included 5 java classes and 5 jar library files.

Then I copied all *.java files and *.jar files to Linux. After I compiled and run it, I got an exception, the class PaserException of htmlparser.jar was not found.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/htmlparser/util/ParserException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.htmlparser.util.ParserException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
```

I just begin to learn Linux so I'm not sure if I compiled and run it correctly.

All of my files(*.java and *.jar) are in the same directory, and my operation is in this directory.

To compile:

```
javac -cp ./htmlparser.jar:./filterbuilder.jar:./sitecapturer.jar:./thumbelina.jar:./htmllexer.jar *.java
```

To run:(the main method is in Crawler class, main method requires at lease 1 argument)

```
java -cp ./htmlparser.jar:./filterbuilder.jar:./sitecapturer.jar:./thumbelina.jar:./htmllexer.jar Crawler arg0 arg1
```

Then I got the exception above. Did I compile and run it correctly? Why did I got this exception? Thanks.

Comment: The java command you specified cannot be correct. The -cp needs to go first. The way you specify it, -cp and everything following it would be an argument to the main method of Crawler. This would produce a different error message though, namely that the Crawler class is not found.

Comment: As you say, if I put the -cp first, but I got a exception of Crawler:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Crawler
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Crawler

Comment: So could you please teach me the right way to run it?

Comment: Is Your program use JavaFX if true download [java oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

Comment: No, I did not use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder that holds the class file (`.`) is not on the classpath. Add another `:.` to the classpath:

```
java -cp ./htmlparser.jar:./filterbuilder.jar:./sitecapturer.jar:./thumbelina.jar:./htmllexer.jar:. Crawler arg0 arg1
```